# Template parameter involved in multiplication is cast to float

Tags: c++, templates, casting

Sorry for the unclear title but I really don't know how to express it.

I have a `CurveSegment` class which does interpolation on a generic parameter and it is structured like this:

```
template<class T>
class CurveSegment
{
public:
    inline void interpolate(float t)
    {
        mCurrentValue = mV0 + mSpan * mInterpolator->interpolate(t);
    }

private:
    T mCurrentValue;
    T mV0;
    T mSpan;
}
```

`mInterpolator->interpolate(t)` returns a float.

I was kinda assuming that, if T has overloaded multiplication and addition operators with a float rhs, the compiler would infer that at instance level and do the operations using the type T.
Instead I get the warning "=: conversion from float to T, possible loss of data", so I imagine that everything gets cast to a float before assignment and I clearly don't know something about the rules involved.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where is `mInterpolator` and its implementation? Likely you have some sort of assignment or implicit conversion from `float t` to `T` and you aren't using the `T::operator + ` or anything.

Comment: Post the class definition of the template argument used and all the relevant functions at namespace scope that could be involved.

Comment: if `T` is int you have `int = int + int * float`. `int * float` -> `float`; `int + float` -> `float`; `int = float` -> warning.

Comment: "T has overloaded multiplication and addition operators with a float rhs" is not enough information to figure out what's going on. Some actual specifics about T, and its overloads, and `mInterpolator->interpolate`, are necessary. (It may be the case that you can cut this down and still have a code example that demonstrates your problem. For instance, if you just use some float literal instead of `mInterpolator->interpolate(t)`, do you still get the warning?)

Comment: @Brandon, mInterpolator Is a pointer to an abstract class that has various implementations for interpolate(t). The one I'm using for testing just returns t.

Comment: @Jarod42 I think you have pointed the exact problem here, and I shouldn't post questions when I'm so tired. I guess I have to rethink this thing.

Comment: @NathanPierson I tried with a float literal and the warning is still there as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Jarod42 in the comments has pointed out exactly where the warning is coming from:

> if T is int you have int = int + int * float. > int * float -> float; int + float -> float; > > int = float -> warning.

I was testing with simple types, `int` included, so here is the reason for this warning. But this shows a flaw in how I structured this code, so I'm going to rethink it.

Thanks everyone for the quick assistance.